# os.chdir() giving error with parsing the path

Tags: python

I am getting error while trying to change the Current directory to a different folder in python. My code is as below:

I take PATH_DIR as input from user and the user passes absolute path.

```
files[]
for directories in os.listdir(PATH_DIR):
        files.append(directories)
for dir in files:
    abs = os.path.abspath(dir)
    print abs
    os.chdir(abs)
```

In my compilation trail I give the PATH_DIR as C:\Python27\Scripts and the directories in this folder are 'WIN7' 'WIN8'. When I execute the program, I get an error as below. 
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:\Python27\Scripts\WIN7'
In principle, the command os.chdir() is some how adding a '\' character before every '\' in the directory path. Can you please help me solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

`os.chdir(abs)`

You are trying to cd into FILE.

[**`os.listdir()`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html) will return full content of given directory.

You need to check whether entity is a directory with [**`os.path.isdir()`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.isdir)

```
import os

PATH_DIR = '.'

files = []
for directory in os.listdir(PATH_DIR):
    print os.path.isdir(os.path.join('.', directory))
    if os.path.isdir(os.path.join('.', directory)):
        files.append(directory)
print files
for directory in files:
    abs_path = os.path.abspath(directory)
    print abs_path
    os.chdir(abs_path)
```

Comment: Thanks for replying to my query. I incorporated your suggestion to my code and verified it. However, I still see the same error. Can you help me.